# Repetir texto várias vezes em Python

Tags: python, string, estrutura-de-dados

Quero repetir um texto várias vezes substituindo apenas alguns elementos(variáveis) nesse texto abaixo entre aspas.

"ont-lineprofile gpon profile-id **417** profile-name "**CT-0318**"

tcont 1 dba-profile-id 10

gem add 1 eth tcont 1

gem mapping 1 0 vlan **318** priority 0

commit

quit"

Este texto que eu quero repetir, e os campos em negrito são as variais para mudar, somando sempre mais 1 a cada repetição e com os devidos espaços como no exemplo.

alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score -1):

Podemos usar um ciclo, incrementar as variáveis e usar a função zfill para pôr os zeros.

```
profile_id = 0
profile_name_nr = 0
vlan = 0

for i in range(1000):
    profile_id += 1
    profile_name_nr += 1
    profile_name = "CT-" + str(profile_name_nr).zfill(4)
    vlan += 1

    command = """
        ont-lineprofile gpon profile-id {0} profile-name "{1}"

        tcont 1 dba-profile-id 10

        gem add 1 eth tcont 1

        gem mapping 1 0 vlan {2} priority 0

        commit

        quit
    """.format(str(profile_id), profile_name, str(vlan))

    print(command)
```